# Microeconomic Model of Knowledge and Technology

Tags: microeconomics, simulations, economic-growth, technology

Can you point me to any microeconomic models of knowledge and technology?

It is intended to be used for simulation.

The problem that arises is that you need to simulate the effects of technology on the economy without knowing anything concrete about the technology and knowledge. 
But the technological breakthroughs are not random. They have a pattern that needs to be modeled.

I made [my own model](http://xekoukou.github.io/economic_simulation/simple_robinson.html) but there are too many magic numbers and distributions that I will be using.

Please note that it is still in development, so it is internally inconsistent. So treat it as a series of thoughts at the moment.

Comment: Look at Schumpeterian growth models. This kind of models are micro-founded models. For innovation, you can simply say that it follows a Poisson distribution. The innovation is a stochastic process for a firm but by the law of large numbers, you can say that aggregate innovation is deterministic. (see Aghion and Howitt (1998))